# How to run the Angular 4 Application by building the JS files in a separate folder and watching the files?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-template

I was trying to learn Angular 4. When referencing the angular tutorial, I was able to run the application but when running the "npm start", the system creates the build files in the same src folder. Here I'm trying to get the JS files created in a separate folder called build, like "src/app/build" and run it off there. Could someone please help on this query? 
Thanks in Advance.
https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6

Comment: what is your IDE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kickstart an Angular Project with [AngularCLI](https://cli.angular.io/) and use ng serve it simplifies everything!

Comment: thanks for the response. I did that but the *.js files gets generated in the src/app path that mixes up with *.ts files. I'm trying to get the build files inside src/app/build. I am running the code in the Mac terminal for your info.

Comment: It's totally fine to get those files mixed up you could use an IDE which has the optlon to hide the .js files if a .ts exists (VS Code, Jetbrains IDE, Atom)

I dont know if there is a way to seperate those files

Answer (score 0):

It is your `IDE` creating that mess due to it is Auto Transpiring the `.ts` in to `.js`. You have to disable that.

If you using `JetBrains IDE` you have to make sure that `Enable TypeScript compiler` is disabled in `Preferences > Languages & Frameworks > TypeScript`.

In case of `Atom` you need to set `compileOnSave: false` in `tsconfig.json`

`VScode` is not auto transpiling `.ts` files unless you have `watcher/task runner` [manually setup](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/typescript) yourself

But usually we are using [angular cli](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli) for any angular project

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
ng new my-proj
cd my-proj
ng serve
```

Comment: This partially answers my question, but I believe my question is focussed on the watcher/task runner part. I have started researching on 'gulp build' and also updating the 'compiler Options {}' with 'outDir' in tsconfig.json would prove to solve this issue. I will post what I find. But anyway thanks for your turn around.